# Quais as diferenças entres as formas de comparação de strings do C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, comparação

```
a.CompareTo(b) == 0
a.Equals(b))
a == b
```

Por que usar cada um deles? Quais vantagens de desvantagens? Algum é mais rápido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A escolha óbvia deve ser sempre o operador de igualdade. Inclusive porque ele chama o método `Equals()`, então chamar o método não faz muito sentido. Até porque dará erro se `a` no exemplo for nulo. O operador dará falso porque nulo é diferente de tudo. De qualquer forma hoje a preferência deveria ser por trabalhar sem nulos quase o tempo todo.

O método só faz sentido se for usar [uma das sobrecargas que permite configurar como deseja a comparação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), selecionando cultura ou algum critério específico.

O método [`CompareTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) não deve ser usado diretamente para comparações. Ele retorna um número positivo, negativo ou neutro para justamente algoritmos que precisam saber da característica ser uma dessas três, que precise do número sobre qual é a situação, como em classificação por exemplo. É uma forma otimizada de fazer isso. Então em um `if` provavelmente não vai querer usá-lo.

O operador e o método são iguais em desempenho, o `CompareTo()` é mais lento, mas ele entrega um resultado que pode eliminar algumas comparações por entregar se é maior, menor ou igual, pode ter economia.

[O código fonte pode ser visto](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Comparison.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).